# codigo python sqlite3 error! permite eliminar registros protegidos por clave foranea

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Tengo creada una tabla de productos, que contiene el Id de la categoria a la que pertenece, ese id es clave foranea en la tabla productos y clave principal en la tabla categorias.
En el gestor DB browser al tratar de eliminar una categoria que esta relacionada en la tabla productos si me sale: error deleting record FOREING KEY.
Pero cuando lo hago desde el programa que estoy creando en python si **se elimina la categoria sin importar que ya esta vinculada a un producto**.
No se porque no lanza el error para que no se pueda eliminar.
Copio una parte funcional del codigo.

Que cambios debería hacer para que si se tenga en cuenta la FOREING KEY y no permita eliminar una categoria que esta referenciada en otra tabla?

Agradezco mucho su colaboración.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

def crear_tablas():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("basedatos2")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
    tablas_creadas = ""

    try:
        miCursor.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE categorias (
                    CATEGORIA_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                    CATEG_NOMBRE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    CUENTA_VENTA VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                    CUENTA_COMPRA VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                    NOTAS VARCHAR(50))
                    """)
        tablas_creadas = tablas_creadas + "- categorias"
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("CONEXIÓN", "Conexión exitosa con la tabla categorias")

    try:
        miCursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE productos (
            PROD_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            CODIGO VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            NOMBRE_PROD VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            CAT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            ID_IMPUESTO INTEGER NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (ID_IMPUESTO) REFERENCES impuestos(IMPTO_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
            FOREIGN KEY (CAT_ID) REFERENCES categorias(CATEGORIA_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT)
            """)
        tablas_creadas = tablas_creadas + "- productos"
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("CONEXIÓN", "Conexión exitosa con la tabla productos")
    print("Se crearon las tablas: " + tablas_creadas)

def insertar_datos_cat(datos):
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("basedatos2")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

    try:
        miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO categorias VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)", (datos))
        miConexion.commit()
        print("Insertado con exito")
        return True
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        if format(e) == "UNIQUE constraint failed: categorias.CATEG_NOMBRE":
            print("El nombre de la categoria ya existe")
        else:
            print(format(e))
    return False

def insertar_datos_prod(datos):
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("basedatos2")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()

    try:
        miCursor.execute("INSERT INTO productos VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?)", (datos))
        miConexion.commit()
        print("Insertado con exito")
        return True
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print(format(e))
    return False

def Eliminar_categoria(id_a_borrar):
    Id = str(id_a_borrar)
    opcion = messagebox.askyesno("ELIMINAR CATEGORIA", "Esta seguro de eliminar la categoría ")
    if opcion == True:
        miConexion = sqlite3.connect("basedatos2")
        miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
        consulta = "DELETE FROM categorias WHERE CATEGORIA_ID ="+ Id
        try:
            miCursor.execute(consulta)
            miConexion.commit()
            print("se eliminó la categoría")
        except:
            messagebox.showwarning("ADVERTENCIA", "Ocurrio un error al eliminar el registro")

crear_tablas()

datos_cat=('Cat prueba', '4140', 'nn','nn')
datos_cat2=('Categoria 2', '414015', 'nn','nn')
insertar_datos_cat(datos_cat) # esta categoria tendría el ID=1
insertar_datos_cat(datos_cat2) # esta categoria tendría el ID=2

datos_prod=('001', 'Prod prueba', 1, 2)
datos_prod2=('002', 'Prod prueba', 2, 2)
insertar_datos_prod(datos_prod)
insertar_datos_prod(datos_prod2)

Eliminar_categoria(1) #Esta linea deberia lanzar la excepcion pero no lo hace y elimina la categoria.
```

Comment: Buen día, intenta agregando `pragma foreign_keys=on` al inicio del primer `execute`, si te funciona me avisas para explicar la razón en una respuesta

Comment: Buen día, si haciendo pruebas, me funciono con pragma foreing_keys = 1 tanto en la creacion de las tablas como en la sentencia de eliminacion, o de inserción funciona bien. Muchas gracias!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando trabajas con `SQLite` desde Python debes activar el soporte de restricciones de clave externa de `SQLite`, para hacerlo debes enviar una sola vez por conexión el comando `pragma foreign_keys=on` ya que por defecto esta desactivado.

[Aquí](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/) hay un artículo que menciona con más detalles la función de activar/desactivar el soporte de restricciones de claves externas.

A partir de la version 3.6.19 de `SQLite` el valor por defecto de `foreign_keys` es `OFF` pero según la documentación podría cambiar en versiones siguientes por lo que se recomienda configurarlo directamente en la aplicación (Como en este caso que lo estás encendiendo) para evitar incompatibilidades en un futuro en caso de que el valor por defecto cambie.

Información adicional del sitio oficial [aquí](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias, habia buscado bastante sobre foreing keys pero en ninguna parte aclaraban que tocaba encenderlo en python.

Comment: @DannyB,  si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)